# Do I need to find eigenfunctions for inhomogeneous boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My problem is $$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = x^2-x+y^2-y | 0\le x,y \le 1\\ u = \alpha  \text{ on the boundary}$$

Using method of eigenfunction expansions: $$u = \sum_m\sum_n b_{mn}\phi_{mn}$$

where $$b_{mn} = -\frac{4}{\lambda_{mn}}\bigg(\int_0^1\int_0^1 \phi_{mn} (x^2-x+y^2-y)dxdy + \oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{mn} \cdot \hat{n}ds\bigg)$$

The line integral which is effectively the inhomogeneous part is what has me completely stuck. Either I'm doing something completely wrong, or the homogeneous eigenfunction simply does not allow for a nonzero result.

$\phi_{mn}$ is the eigenfunction:

$$\tag{1} \phi_{mn}=\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)$$

For the line integral, I went over my work on it several times, and each time I verify my results, I keep getting 0. Upon further inspection of the equation for $\phi$, it looks to be impossible to not get 0 every single time. So I'm suspecting that I need to find a new set of eigenfunctions for the inhomogeneous part.

---

I'll post my full work below for the line integration:

$$\tag{2}\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{mn} \cdot \hat{n}ds$$. For $\alpha$, you substitute it with the boundary conditions which are:

$$\tag{3}\alpha = \cases{x & $0\le x\le1,y=0$ \\ 1+y & $0\le y \le 1, x=1$ \\ 1+x & $1\ge x\ge 0,y=1$ \\ y & $1\ge y \ge 0, x=0$}$$

$$\tag{4} \nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n} = \pi\Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)\hat{i}\cdot\hat{n} +m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\hat{j}\cdot\hat{n} \Big) \\ = \pi\Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y) +m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y) \Big)$$

Starting with $0 \le x \le 1,y=0$ and going counterclockwise:

$$\tag{5}\pi\int_{C1} xn\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)dx + xm\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)dy \\ dx = dx, dy = 0, x = t, y = 0, ds = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt = \sqrt{(1)^2+(0)^2}dt = dt \\ = n\pi \int_0^1 (t\cos(n\pi t)\sin(m\pi)+0)dt = 0$$

Note: $\sin(n\pi) = \sin(m\pi) = 0$ because n and m are integer values

$$\tag{6}\pi\int_{C2} (1+y)n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)dx + (1+y)m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)dy \\ dx = 0, dy = dy, x = 1, y = t, ds = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt = \sqrt{(0)^2+(1)^2}dt = dt \\ = m\pi\int_0^1 (1+t)\sin(n\pi)\cos(m\pi t)dt = 0$$

$$\tag{7}\pi\int_{C3} (1+x)n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)dx + (1+x)m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)dy \\ dx = dx, dy = 0, x = -t, y = 1, ds = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt = \sqrt{(-1)^2+(0)^2}dt = dt \\ =  n\pi\int_0^1 (1+x)\cos(n\pi(-t))\sin(m\pi 0) ds = 0$$

$$\tag{8}\pi\int_{C4} (y)n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)dx + (y)m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)dy \\ dx = 0, dy = dy, x = 0, y = -t, ds = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt = \sqrt{(0)^2+(-1)^2}dt = dt \\ =  m\pi \int_0^1 y\sin(n\pi 0)\cos(m\pi (-t)) = 0$$

So I get:

$$\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_i \cdot \hat{n}ds = 0$$ which I know is incorrect, because this is only the case if the boundary conditions are homogeneous, which they are not. This is why I suspect my eigenfunction equation for (1) is incorrect and I need to find different ones